# Can $4+(2k)!$ ever be a perfect square over the integers?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, analytic-number-theory, factorial

Is there any pair of natural numbers $\{ k, m \}$ satisfying: $4+(2k)! = m^2$?

I tried simplifying this into

$$ 2^k k!(2k-1)!! = (m-2)(m+2) \text , $$

where !! denotes the double factorial, i.e., $1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \dots \cdot (2k-1) $.

I suppose that this equation has no solutions but could anyone please help me solve it or suggest how to approach it?

Comment: You can prove that *if* there is such a solution, $m$ must be even, by considering that both sides of the equation have a factor of $4$.

Comment: Yes I noticed that and then I tried simplifying further such that m = 2r

Comment: This would in turn bring in this equation $\[(2k)! = 4(r-1)(r+1)\]$

Comment: I have no clue how to proceed further

Comment: Whether this equation has finitely many solutions is an open problem, see *On the Diophantine Equation $x!+ A=y^2$* by Andrzej Dąbrowski for more information. In the same article, known cases are described for small values, there are no such known for $A=4$. So existence of a solution seems to be an open problem as well. What might not be an open problem however, is showing that there is no solution in your case where $x$ is even. This is clearly a weaker statement than non-existence of solutions for any integer $x$.

Comment: Also computionally, it seems that $\frac{4+(2k)!}{4}$ is square-free.

Comment: Are you sure that ${{k,m}}$ can only take natural numbers? Because if $k$ is negative, there will be plenty of solutions.

Comment: This almost definitely only makes it harder, but your problem is equivalent to $\exists k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sin(\pi\sqrt{4+(2k)!})=0$

Comment: Taking the $4$ over to the RHS gives $(2k)!=m^{2}-4$. Then, successively, taking the modulus of the odd prime divisors of $(2k)!$ shows that the $m$ cannot be divisible by any of these odd primes. But not sure this can be utilised further.

Comment: Not that this is very useful, but I've checked up to $k=10,000$ (when $4+(2k)!\approx1.8\times 10^{77,337}$) and found no solution...

Comment: The problem is equivalent to proving that for each $k$, there is a unique positive integer $h$ such that $$\left(h-1\right)\left(h+3\right)<\left(2k\right)!<h\left(h+4\right)$$ Checking out a few examples shows that the $h$'s are quite "random" in the sense that the pattern is far from an obvious or easily recognized one.